# AngularJS filter on unknown object key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array, with objects. Each objects contain's the actual value in the key, and the value is always an empty array.

```
[ { john : [] }, { foo : [] } ] ...etc
```

I'm using the following HTML to render what I need

```
<li ng-repeat="(x,y) in tags" class="tag" style="color: white; padding:5px;">
    <span ng-repeat="(c,d) in y" class="label" ng-style="{'background-color': getTagColor(c)}">{{c}}</span>
</li>
```

Which result in displaying a list, just john, foo in this case.

Now I'm wondering, how am I going to filter on this.. ? A regular filter isn't working. I tried using a object key filter like `<input ng-model="search.$">` but this does not seem to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand right, here `(c,d) in y` `c` stands for `key` and `d` stands for value. So you can pass `key` to custom filter function along with search value and based on these values, filter them

Comment: c is always variable... do u have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was simple

```
.filter('piemel', function(){
return function(items, value){
    var returnList = [];

    if(items){
        for(x in items){
            var tag = Object.keys(items[x])[0].toLowerCase();

            if(value){
                value = value.toLowerCase();
                if( tag.indexOf(value) != -1){
                    returnList.push(items[x]);
                }
            }
            else{
                returnList.push(items[x]);
            }
        }
    }

    return returnList;
};
})
```

and

```
ng-repeat="(x,y) in tags | piemel:searchText"
```